# Using HTML for C++ based desktop application

Tags: html, c++

I was wondering if it is possible to use HTML to create the user interface for a C++ based desktop application. I have tried several actions but I couldn't seem to get it working.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  In fact, entire web browsers have been written in C++, which certainly have html interface.  Are you just looking for a "yes" or "no" answer?

Comment: Q: Is it possible to use HTML to create the user interface for a C++ based desktop application?  A: By itself, C++ doesn't directly support *ANY* UI besides text "std::cin" and "std::cout"  So: Q: what exactly did you have in mind?  Q: What platform is your "desktop": Windows?  MacOS?  Linux?  Q: Would you be willing to generate an .html file and call [system()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) to open the file in a browser?  Q: If so, how are you going to read user input?  Without having a web server?  Yes, it might be "possible" - but we need many more details!

Comment: Search for `WebAssembly`

Answer (score 1):

You could have a c++ program run as a cgi application and pass parameters to it via a web page.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/). It's a combination of Chromium and Node.js which allows you to create native desktop applications using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. By using [Node Addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), you can integrate native C++ functions through a statically-linked library. In fact, apps like VS Code are built using Electron.

Comment: the OP asked a hopelessly vague question ... but "Electron" is absolutely a good suggestion.  I have no idea why you were marked down.